# In Safari, how can I allow a site to locate me, after I have refused?

Tags: ipad, safari, mobile-safari, geolocation, web-browsing

In Safari on iOS 8 on my iPad, I went to a page on the site *www.castorama.fr*. 
The page wanted to locate me. So Safari asked me, and I refused (too quickly).

Now, I want to accept.

**1) How can I accept to be located?**

I have a few more questions about location in Safari.

2) When I refuse, will Safari ask me again if I visit the page again after some time? If so, how much time?

3) When I refuse, does this apply to the page or to the whole site?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer in the following order

3 - Settings are remembered for the whole site. Not for the page.

2 - There is a settings under Preferences -> Privacy, for this. You can select either to be prompted once a day, only once or deny all the time.

1 - I don't think there is no way to do this directly. But I think you can work around it by changing the settings in answer 2 to prompt daily, visit your website, allow locations when prompted and disable the settings back to prompt once if you want to

More on location services https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204690